# (FFMPEG) How I can be batch render videos with one image + videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have about 30 videos in one folder. I want to add a picture to videos but it must be full scale image and it should be viewing from beginning to end of video. How I can do that? Thank you..

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Hi ,@llogan Windows 8

Comment: Use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) and adapt [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273691/1109017) for the batch.